# Hadoop got Expected JSON. Is WebHDFS enabled? Got ''

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have serveral csv file in hadoop already, when I try

```
hdfs = pyhdfs.HdfsClient(hosts='34.71.193.160:8123', user_name='root')

files_name = hdfs.listdir('/user/input/')
```

Got this error message, can't find how to fix

```
HdfsException: Expected JSON. Is WebHDFS enabled? Got ''
```

Comment: What is `34.160:8123/`? The hosts expect a valid namenode IP address(es).

Comment: jus wrong typing, fix now. Actually not even sure if this is the right host, but I think I correct because it able to connect to this host.

Comment: But is that the host where hadoop is running, I do not think 8123 is the correct port. Try this `curl -i "http://34.71.193.160:8123/webhdfs/v1/tmp?user.name=root&op=GETFILESTATUS"`?

Comment: invalid syntax, I'm doing the stuff on Jupyte Notebook Pyspark

Comment: No that is not enough. You should have a hadoop cluster (atleast in pseudo distributed mode) running to access webhdfs.

Comment: My notebook is create from Google Cloud Dataproc Cluster, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing the stuff on Jupyte Notebook Pyspark

Spark can read from the NameNode directly. Don't use WebHDFS

e.g. reading all files in a directory line by line

```
df = spark.read.csv("/user/input")
df.show()
```

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/